# VLC for Android Compilation Error

Tags: android, ubuntu, vlc

I want to compile VLC for Android on Ubuntu 12.10.I already updated all the necessary tools and follow the whole procedure as described on http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile but when compile the source code it give error that VLC source not found and everytime starts downloading VLC source code for Windows

```
xyz@ubuntu:~$export ANDROID_SDK=/home/xyz/Android/android-sdk
xyz@ubuntu:~$export ANDROID_NDK=/home/xyz/Android/android-ndk
xyz@ubuntu:~$export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/tools
xyz@ubuntu:~$export ANDROID_ABI=armeabi
xyz@ubuntu:~$export NO_FPU=1
xyz@ubuntu:~$git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git
xyz@ubuntu:~$sh compile.sh
sh:0:Can't open compile.sh
xyz@ubuntu:~$cd /home/xyz/Android/android/
xyz@ubuntu:~/android$sh compile.sh
For an ARMv6 device without FPU:
$export NO_FPU=1
For an ARMv5 device:
$export NO_ARMv6=1
VLC source not found,cloning          //It starts downloading VLC source for windows
Cloning into 'vlc'.....
remote:Counting objects:403786,done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Every time when I compile it shows VLC source not found and starts downloading VLC for windows source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you need to run sudo chmod a+x -R android/ to start because the git clone can't access the android/ directory and it might be defaulting to the next available OS, which could be Windows.